# How to write such JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Honestly i am curious to know how this types of codes can be written? I really want to learn. i don't know why but it looks funny to me. I can't understand it at all. i can only read when i decode it with http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

Here is my point, how to write such codes?

Demo:(Only an example)

```
    var _0x66ee=["\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x23\x6D\x61\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E","\x68\x69\x64\x65","\x23\x62\x74\x6E\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x73\x68\x6F\x77","\x23\x62\x74\x6E\x2D\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72","\x2E\x6C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x5F\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74","\x3C\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3E\x3C\x62\x72\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x69\x67\x74\x62\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x73\x69\x74\x65\x73\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C\x2F\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x2F\x74\x62\x5F\x77\x61\x6C\x6C\x2F\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73\x2F\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x69\x6E\x67\x2D\x69\x6D\x67\x2E\x67\x69\x66\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x6D\x67\x3E\x20\u0110\x61\x6E\x67\x20\u0111\u0103\x6E\x67\x20\x78\x75\u1EA5\x74\x20\x76\x75\x69\x20\x6C\xF2\x6E\x67\x20\u0111\u1EE3\x69\x20\x74\x72\x6F\x6E\x67\x20\x67\x69\xE2\x79\x20\x6C\xE1\x74\x20\x3C\x2F\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3E","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x75\x74\x3D\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x75\x74","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x2E\x70\x68\x70","\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x23\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x75\x74","\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73","\x3C\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3E\x3C\x62\x72\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x69\x67\x74\x62\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x73\x69\x74\x65\x73\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C\x2F\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x2F\x74\x62\x5F\x77\x61\x6C\x6C\x2F\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x73\x2F\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x69\x6E\x67\x2D\x69\x6D\x67\x2E\x67\x69\x66\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x6D\x67\x3E\x20\u0110\x61\x6E\x67\x20\x78\u1EED\x20\x6C\xFD\x20\u0111\u0103\x6E\x67\x20\x6E\x68\u1EAD\x70\x20\x76\x75\x69\x20\x6C\xF2\x6E\x67\x20\u0111\u1EE3\x69\x20\x74\x72\x6F\x6E\x67\x20\x67\x69\xE2\x79\x20\x6C\xE1\x74\x20\x3C\x2F\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3E","\x76\x61\x6C","","\x3C\x62\x72\x3E\x3C\x6C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x61\x6C\x65\x72\x74\x20\x61\x6C\x65\x72\x74\x2D\x64\x61\x6E\x67\x65\x72\x22\x3E\x42\u1EA1\x6E\x20\x63\x68\u01B0\x61\x20\x6E\x68\u1EAD\x70\x20\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E\x20\x76\x75\x69\x20\x6C\xF2\x6E\x67\x20\x6C\u1EA5\x79\x20\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E\x20\u0111\u0103\x6E\x67\x20\x6E\x68\u1EAD\x70\x20\x6C\u1EA1\x69\x2E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E","\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E\x3D","\x64\x61\x6E\x67\x6E\x68\x61\x70\x2E\x70\x68\x70","\x23\x6C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"]
var _0x8d8f=[_0x66ee[0],_0x66ee[1],_0x66ee[2],_0x66ee[3],_0x66ee[4],_0x66ee[5],_0x66ee[6],_0x66ee[7],_0x66ee[8],_0x66ee[9],_0x66ee[10],_0x66ee[11],_0x66ee[12],_0x66ee[13],_0x66ee[14],_0x66ee[15],_0x66ee[16],_0x66ee[17],_0x66ee[18],_0x66ee[19],_0x66ee[20],_0x66ee[21],_0x66ee[22],_0x66ee[23],_0x66ee[24],_0x66ee[25]]
var _0xa1dc=[_0x8d8f[0],_0x8d8f[1],_0x8d8f[2],_0x8d8f[3],_0x8d8f[4],_0x8d8f[5],_0x8d8f[6],_0x8d8f[7],_0x8d8f[8],_0x8d8f[9],_0x8d8f[10],_0x8d8f[11],_0x8d8f[12],_0x8d8f[13],_0x8d8f[14],_0x8d8f[15],_0x8d8f[16],_0x8d8f[17],_0x8d8f[18],_0x8d8f[19],_0x8d8f[20],_0x8d8f[21],_0x8d8f[22],_0x8d8f[23],_0x8d8f[24],_0x8d8f[25]];
var _0x951b=[_0xa1dc[0],_0xa1dc[1],_0xa1dc[2],_0xa1dc[3],_0xa1dc[4],_0xa1dc[5],_0xa1dc[6],_0xa1dc[7],_0xa1dc[8],_0xa1dc[9],_0xa1dc[10],_0xa1dc[11],_0xa1dc[12],_0xa1dc[13],_0xa1dc[14],_0xa1dc[15],_0xa1dc[16],_0xa1dc[17],_0xa1dc[18],_0xa1dc[19],_0xa1dc[20],_0xa1dc[21],_0xa1dc[22],_0xa1dc[23],_0xa1dc[24],_0xa1dc[25]];
function btn_load(_0x8c7ax5)
{
    _0x8c7ax5[_0x951b[1]](_0x951b[0],_0x951b[0]);
    $(_0x951b[2])[_0x951b[1]](_0x951b[0],_0x951b[0]);
    $(_0x951b[4])[_0x951b[3]]();
    $(_0x951b[6])[_0x951b[5]]()
}
function btn_reset(_0x8c7ax5)
{
    _0x8c7ax5[_0x951b[7]](_0x951b[0]);
    $(_0x951b[2])[_0x951b[7]](_0x951b[0]);
    $(_0x951b[4])[_0x951b[5]]();
    $(_0x951b[6])[_0x951b[3]]()
}
$(document)[_0x951b[25]](function()
{
    $(_0x951b[16])[_0x951b[15]](function()
    {
        var _0x8c7ax7=$(_0x951b[8]);
        _0x8c7ax7[_0x951b[10]](_0x951b[9]);
        var _0x8c7ax8=_0x951b[11];
        $[_0x951b[14]]({type:_0x951b[12],data:_0x8c7ax8,url:_0x951b[13],success:function(_0x8c7ax9)
        {
            _0x8c7ax7[_0x951b[10]](_0x8c7ax9)
        }
        })
    }
    );
    $(_0x951b[2])[_0x951b[17]]();
    $(_0x951b[24])[_0x951b[15]](function()
    {
        var _0x8c7axa=$(_0x951b[2]);
        var _0x8c7ax7=$(_0x951b[8]);
        _0x8c7ax7[_0x951b[10]](_0x951b[18]);
        if(_0x8c7axa[_0x951b[19]]()==_0x951b[20])
        {
            $[_0x951b[14]]({success:function(_0x8c7ax9)
            {
                _0x8c7ax7[_0x951b[10]](_0x951b[21]);
                btn_reset(button)
            }
            });
            return false
        }
        ;
        if(_0x8c7axa[_0x951b[19]]()!=_0x951b[20])
        {
            var _0x8c7axb=_0x951b[22]+_0x8c7axa[_0x951b[19]]();
            $[_0x951b[14]]({type:_0x951b[12],data:_0x8c7axb,url:_0x951b[23],success:function(_0x8c7ax9)
            {
                _0x8c7ax7[_0x951b[10]](_0x8c7ax9);
                btn_reset(button)
            }
            })
        }
        ;
        return false
    }
    );
    $(_0x951b[24])[_0x951b[15]](function()
    {
        button=$(this);
        btn_load(button)
    }
    )
}
)\x64\x61\x6E\x67\x6E\x68\x61\x70\x2E\x70\x68\x70
```

??????

Comment: You don't. You write JS and then obfuscate it.

Comment: how to encode? explain plz

Comment: Use an uglifier/minifier/obfuscator. (It's not an "encoding", btw)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few of these before, Heres one where you can convert any javascript code to be displayed in just a few sequences of characters

http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

Has an explanation also :)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, it seems that the person who wrote this code just created some string in the variables in the global variables. He just replaced the letters and character with Unicode. That's the only trick.

It's just tricky. There is no magic beyond.